# Syntax error on token "@", invalid AssignmentOperator

Tags: java

my code looks like this:

```
Student jackNapoli = new Student(3, Jack, Napoli, The_Lawyer99@yahoo.com, 19, 85,84,87);
```

I am trying to create an new object of the Student class. My problem is the @ symbol in the email address. How do I get this to not show up as error?

Comment: Use quotes: `"Jack", "Napoli", "The_Lawyer99@yahoo.com",`

Comment: It is surprising that you don't saw error messages for Jack and Napoli. Or do you have objects (variables) that are named Jack and Napoli? And btw: sure, this is an absolute beginner question; but why the many downvotes?

Comment: @EddyG he did not saw the error message on the other because the syntax is valid. Syntax is validated before the reference, however the email address syntax is invalid as it use the "@" which is reserved for annotation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the `@` symbol.

The way you are passing the parameters to `Student`, *Jack*, *Napoli* and *The_Lawyer99@yahoo.com* are seen as object.

The compiler might tell you the problem is with the `@` because it is reserved for annotation in java. However, the real problem is that you probably want to pass these values as string using quotes.

```
Student jackNapoli = new Student(3, "Jack", "Napoli", "The_Lawyer99@yahoo.com", 19, 85,84,87);
```